# Dropzone delete uploaded images database and server

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, dropzone.js, dropzone

i am working with dropzone. Right now when image dragged successfully saved.

When clicked delete it removes the file what we expect.

But when page load, previously files are displaying and clicking removes. It does not remove the file. I don't know why? What should i add? or remove? or change?

These are my codes:

```
var total_photos_counter = 0;
    var dropZone = new Dropzone('#my-dropzone',{
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 2,
    maxFilesize: 4,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',
    dictFileTooBig: 'Limit: 4MB',
    timeout: 10000,
    init: function () {
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
            $.post({
                url: '/images-delete',
                data: {id: file.name, _token: $('[name="_token"]').val()},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    total_photos_counter--;
                    $("#counter").text("# " + total_photos_counter);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    success: function (file, done) {
        total_photos_counter++;
        $("#counter").text("# " + total_photos_counter);
    }
});



for (i = 0; i < existingFiles.length; i++) {
    dropZone.emit("addedfile", existingFiles[i]);
    dropZone.emit("thumbnail", existingFiles[i], existingFiles[i].url);
    dropZone.emit("complete", existingFiles[i]);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove

```
`for (i = 0; i < existingFiles.length; i++) {
    dropZone.emit("addedfile", existingFiles[i]);
    dropZone.emit("thumbnail", existingFiles[i], existingFiles[i].url);
    dropZone.emit("complete", existingFiles[i]);
}`
```

because this code is run when page loaded twice